# ffmpeg -shortest not giving correct length

Tags: ffmpeg

I am taking a movie and splitting it apart into multiple movies using the segment option.  For some reason, in quite a few of these split apart movies the audio is extended slightly longer in duration, so I have opted to use the -shortest flag, but it is not working.  Am I doing something wrong here?

```
ffmpeg -i main_mov_2019_05_20.mov -f -segment -segment_frames 123, 164 -reset_timestamps 1 -c copy -shortest -map 0 "%03d_test20.mov"
```

[See Video and Audio Length Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJjWl.png)

I am running ffmpeg 2.6.3